# Making flaming particles?

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation, fire

I have an animation I am trying to make of a flaming object emitting particles. I need the particles to be on fire though, and emit smoke. I have already tried faking it by placing the object that the particles are mimicking inside the smoke domain, but the fire does not appear. Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: I believe you also need to enable smoke flow in the physics tab for these particles after placing them in the domain. I'm not sure if you need to do that for the particle emitter object or for the original duplicated object. Better try out both, but I suspect the first.

Comment: I already added smoke settings for the particle object if that's what you mean.

Comment: Ah found the option, I've posted a screenshot as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the flow source on the emitter within the domain to Particle System, and select your particle system.

You can then set the size of those particles below. It will always be a spherical inflow shape, it doesn't take in account any object you set as the particle render shape.

[image: Flow source]

Comment: Yep that was it. Can't believe I missed something so simple.

Comment: Sometimes the answer is right under our noses! Happy to help you learn, and learned something myself

Answer (score 1):

Hi I'd like to add that this ALMOST solves it, but make sure you select inflow under the flow behavior settings!!! Been bugging me for days and I'm a long time simulator in blender. Sometimes it's hard to keep track of all these little details and hope it helps someone